# How to get the kids of a txt tree in partykit format

Tags: r, party

If you run the following:

```
library(RWeka) 
data(iris) 
res = J48(Species ~., data = iris)
```

you will get the following tree:

```
R> res
J48 pruned tree
------------------

Petal.Width <= 0.6: setosa (50.0)
Petal.Width > 0.6
|   Petal.Width <= 1.7
|   |   Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (48.0/1.0)
|   |   Petal.Length > 4.9
|   |   |   Petal.Width <= 1.5: virginica (3.0)
|   |   |   Petal.Width > 1.5: versicolor (3.0/1.0)
|   Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (46.0/1.0)

Number of Leaves  :     5

Size of the tree :  9
```

Now copy and paste it into a text file and save it - this is my input file.
I would like to get the list of each node (father) and its kids of the tree (it is only an example) in a format as if I ran this tree in R and used the as.party. (remember I can't use it since it is only a txt format).
I would like to get the list of nodes and their kids in the same way as if used x$kids in partykit package.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, this is possible but it is likely to be error prone. And even if it works it won't contain all information that `as.party(res)` contains. For example, some variables from the original data (`Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width`) cannot be inferred here. Similarly, it would be possible that not all response levels can be inferred in the case where some level is not the most frequent level in any of the terminal nodes. The frequencies associated with all response levels in all terminal nodes are also likely to be not fully reconstructable.

In short: The `partykit` package avoids plain text parsing when coercing trees from other packages because the results might be wrong/incomplete. Converting the objects (rather their text representation) works reliably.

Comment: Achim, Thanks a lot. Can you please show how can I do it from txt file?

Comment: No, sorry, as explained above: It won't work in general, hence I don't think it's worth spending time on this. If you want to do it, you will have to `readLines` the file and then use the usual text processing functions for the parsing: `grep`, `gsub`, `strsplit`, `paste`, etc.